# Cannot disable d3 topojson base map zooming on Ionic V5 App

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, svg, ionic5

I am trying to make the zooming functionality of a d3 topology map smoother on my app. The default zooming behavior are kind of lag a lot and mostly it conflicts with ionic touch events. I am trying to disable all default zooming features completely and will try to do it with zoom in/out buttons.. But it seems I cannot disable zoom.

Here is my markup

[image]

And here is my map code ...

[image]

Though I cannot pinch zoom on the map, but it seems I can zoom the svg by pinching the white area outside the map. I want to disable the pinch zoom completely so user cannot zoom it using touch.

Comment: I think you could put a div above the map, and give this div a transparent background, so when user touch the div it will give not effect since it is the div and not the map, and then you can do your zooming using 2 buttons zoom in/ zoom out

Comment: I don't think it will work, as the <svg> tag has a 100% height and width attribute. So it is covering the whole visible area. But I'll try and update you shortly. Also I have tried adding the zoom event on d3 element, it does not work either..  this._svg.on("zoom", (ev: any) => this.zoom(ev));  and then in zoom() function I have a console.log(), but nothing logs in console.. The zoom event is not fired as well.. I'll update you shortly with the DIV.

Comment: Till now i didn't get the point of svg but try and if it didn't work then tell me what is svg lol.

Comment: You know what? It worked.. The SVG is basically the d3 map container :) LOL. Let me try to invoke the d3 zoom event now :) Thanks you!

Comment: Yup , when i told you to make a new did i worked as you named the map svg but after you told me then what to do with svg then thought its something other than map. ^_^. Do i add it as answer or still you have question?

Comment: Yes sure ! please add it to he answer.. Over all I could disable the zoom by pinching outside of the map. Now I'll try to enable the zoom event of d3. If I fail, then my last option will be to add the zoom in/out button :(

Comment: What do you mean by enable zoom event of d3.

Comment: d3 has an inbuild zoom event handler. I am trying to enable that like this... this._svg.on("zoom", (ev: any) => {
          console.log("zoom invoked");
          console.log(ev);
          this._svg.transition().call(this._zoom.scaleBy, 1.5);
        });  But seems like I can't :(

Comment: On the div overlay you added , maybe you can do ontouchstart and ontouchend or add a gesture for detecting figer zoom in or out, and then trigger your zooming from this gesture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put a div above the map, and give this div a transparent background and give it height and width as the map size, so when user touch the div it will give no effect since it is the div and not the map, and then you can do your zooming using 2 buttons (zoom in/ zoom out).